# Mask Values on Foreground Extraction

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working on this code to perform foreground extraction but I don't understand the meaning of  `mask2 = np.where((mask==2 | (mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8'))` and `img = img*mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]` lines. Here is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('tut12img.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2], np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65), np.float64)

rect = (161, 79, 150, 150)

cv2.grabCut(img, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Why musk is zero when it is 2 or 0? What is special about it? what kind of matrix is musk2? Thanks!

code and photo comes from https://pythonprogramming.net/grabcut-foreground-extraction-python-opencv-tutorial/?completed=/template-matching-python-opencv-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mask2 is the foreground mask. so you only use foreground pixels which is done by setting every pixel 0 that is background, else 1

```
mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
```

Pixels are put into 4 classes.

- background (0)
- foreground (1)
- probably background (2)
- probably foreground (3)

Of course it would have been more obvious if the author of that code would have used the proper flags like cv2.GC_BGD instead of 0...

Also mask2 might not be the most informative name.

It is all in the OpenCV manual. All you have to do is google 1-2 words and read 1 paragraph...

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga909c1dda50efcbeaa3ce126be862b37f

> mask  Input/output 8-bit single-channel mask. The mask is initialized
>   by the function when mode is set to GC_INIT_WITH_RECT. Its elements
>   may have one of the cv::GrabCutClasses.

and

> enum cv::GrabCutClasses
>
> class of the pixel in GrabCut algorithm
>
> GC_BGD     an obvious background pixels
>
> GC_FGD     an obvious foreground (object) pixel
>
> GC_PR_BGD      a possible background pixel
>
> GC_PR_FGD      a possible foreground pixel